# How to send systemd logs to a text file

Tags: systemd, logs, text

I want to know how to send systemd logs to a text file.

There are many reasons for this, such as:

1. Being able to use grep without having to use journalctl first
2. Being accustomed to it
3. Why not use it

ideally in conjunction with systemd-journal

Answer (score 2):

- `sudo journalctl > /tmp/system.log` as a one time command or `sudo journalctl -f > /tmp/system.log` to continuously update the resulting log file.
- `ForwardToSyslog=yes` + install any "classic" system logger, e.g. `rsyslog`.